# Another query question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry another question: If I have a field called 'sheet_id' and 'specimen_id' in a model called specimen and i need to say take the last 'sheet_id' and print the 'specimen_id' for that 'sheet_id' would it be something like this:

```
(Specimen.last.sheet_id == '?').each do |specimen| %>


<%= specimen.specimen_id %> <% end %>
```

I think the 'each' is misplaced.  Any ideas?

Comment: your specimen should only have id. not specimen_id

Comment: and you don't need to loop. just need: Specimen.last.sheet_id

Comment: you dont need to loop through them using each. you only need to select the last right?

Comment: I need to select the last sheet_id, yes, but I also need to display the values of the fields that have the last sheet_id.  Not sure if I explained it well

Comment: If i understand well, you want to display all the specimen_id from the specimen model which have the same sheet_id ?

Answer (score 0):

If by "take the last 'sheet_id'" you mean taking the specimen with the highest sheet_id value, that would be:

```
Specimen.last(:order => :sheet_id).specimen_id
```

If you want the last speciment with a specific sheet_id, it would be:

```
Specimen.find_last_by_sheet_id(42).specimen_id
```

Comment: Thank, but where does the .each go?  This is failing:

Comment: Specimen.last(:order => :distribution_sheet_id).each do |specimen|

Comment: There is no need for each as you only want the last, just: <%= Specimen.last(:order => :distribution_sheet_id).specimen_id =>